# Transporting plain text and encrypted data together

Tags: security, encryption

I have a web service that encrypts/decrypts data. Is there any harm (from the security standpoint) if my service returns both the plaintext and the encrypted text together as part of the response? I am trying to find out if it makes it any easier for anyone trying to break the system and steal the key if they are able to get hold of the plaintext and ciphertext together, as opposed to getting hold of the only the encrypted data. Algorighm used is AES-256 to encrypt data.

**Update**: To clarify, the scenario is more about the decryption(and not encryption). My service needs to take in a list of encrypted strings and return a list of decrypted strings. To make sure that the consumer is able to map the decrypted values in the response to the encrypted values, i was thinking of sending back a collection of ciphertext/plaintext pairs. I know there are other ways to maintain this mapping(for eg using an sequence number), but I was wondering if a ciphertext/plaintext combination could be used by someone to figure out the original key.

Comment: Am I missing something? What is the point of encryption if you are returning the plaintext as well?

Comment: Yes, that's very insecure. Known plaintext attacks are in chapter 1 of any hacker handbook ;)

Comment: Maybe I should have put "considered" insecure, instead of "very" insecure. In case of AES it has not been done yet, but every cipher remains susceptible to a know-plaintext attack.

Comment: @JohnWillemse If you extend that argument further, you would eventually conclude it's not worth using cryptography at all because all algorithms *could* be broken. I think it's more important to stress that currently there are no known techniques that allow an attacker to derive *any* information about an AES key based on having a plaintext and corresponding ciphertext. Hence, it is secure (in terms of key exposure). But... strange.

Comment: @DuncanJones Yes, I agree, strange. I've looked into it more for a second and have to admit it is highly unlikely it will ever be broken by a known-plaintext attack.

Comment: This question is a better fit for http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, no, a secure cipher is not susceptible to this (referred to as a "[known-plaintext attack.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known_plaintext_attack)")

From the Wikipedia article:

> Modern ciphers such as Advanced Encryption Standard are not currently susceptible to known-plaintext attacks.

I'm curious why you would want to implement such a thing, but I'm sure you have your reasons.  Care to share them?

Comment: _Every_ cipher is suceptible to a known-plaintext attack. It's just more unlikely with AES, but there's no proof that it is not susceptible at all, other than the fact that no-one has been able to do it _so far_.

Comment: _Every_ padlock is susceptible to "magic fairy dust" attacks.  It's just not likely with Master locks, but there's no proof that they are not susceptible at all, other than the fact that no-one has been able to do it so far.  ;)

Comment: Bad analogy. A cipher is inherently susceptible to know-plaintext attacks, that cannot be denied. If you have ever had to deal with security audits, then you would know that sending plaintext and ciphertext in one packet would ring all alarm bells. I am aware it's highly unlikely though ;)

Comment: @ty733420, I have updated my original question to explain the scenario better.

Comment: makes sense, figured it was something like that.